# Rails 3: How to override a method in a gem

Tags: rubygems, monkeypatching, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add some custom code in into one of the methods in a gem. In Rails 2.3.8, I added a .rb file under config/initializers directory, and everything worked perfectly.

Since moved to Rail3, what's working before is not working anymore. I have tried adding a mongoid_slug.rb under config/initializers and under /lib and auto_load the /lib path in application.rb. Both didn't work.

Inside mongoid_slug.rb I have tried:

```
module Mongoid
  module Slug    
     module ClassMethods  
         def find_unique_slug  
             #mycode   
         end  
     end  
  end  
end
```

AND

```
Mongoid::Slug::ClassMethods.module_eval do   
  def find_unique_slug  
    #mycode  
  end  
end
```

And still, both failed. Anybody can offer some tips on how to monkey patch a gem in Rails3?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this works for me,

```
module Mongoid
  module Slug    
     module ClassMethods  
         def find_unique_slug  
             #mycode   
         end  
     end  
  end  
end
```

problem in other, i think that in including this file or calling this methods
should include like:
include Abt::I18n 
in ApplicationHelper or somewhere else